# ForEach to Lambda with two list in C#

Tags: c#, list, lambda

```
foreach (var item in lstObj)
        {
            item.links = new List<ObjTest>();
            foreach (var rel in item.relations)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in lstObj)
                {
                    if (rel.Object_ID2 == item2.ID)
                    {
                        item.links.Add(item2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'd like to change this into lambda expression but i don't get it !

Here is the objects classes :

```
ObjTest
    public int ID
    public string content;
    public List<ObjRelation> relations; //relations with other ObjTest object
    public List<ObjTest> links; //objTest objects of relations

ObjRelation
    public int ID;
    public int object_ID1;       
    public int object_ID2;
```

So an ObjTest contains two list, [relation] and [links]

In [relation] we have a description of relations that an ObjTest has.

In [Links] we have the object(s) linked to the ObjTest, in relation with the object's ids we have in the relations list.

My goal was to put in [links] objects presents in lstObj, but filtered by the ids (object_ID2) presents in [relations] list of each ObjTest in lstObj.

I did it, but i'd like to translate this forEach into lambda expression. I Tried some things but it won't work :/

Comment: `I Tried some things but i won't work` <= please show what you have tried with what did not work (exception details or unexpected result explanation)

Comment: Don't convert `foreach` to Lambda just for the heck of it. Your code is quite clear in itself.

Comment: Linq is meant for filtering and projecting one sequence to another.  You should not use it to mutate the items in the sequence.  So while you might be able to convert some of your code to use Linq you should still use a `foreach` for the mutating parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, but your foreach code is as good as this.

```
listObj.ForEach(item => { item.links = item.relations.Join(listObj.ToList(), x => x.object_ID2, y => y.ID, (x, y) => y); });
```

Comment: Yes but i'm trying to improve my lambda expression skills ahah ! Thanks !

Comment: Resharper is a great Linq teacher. It detects loops than can be converted to Linq expressions.